# reading images from VideoReader gets progressively slower

Tags: matlab, video-capture

I've been trying to to read an MP4 file using VideoReader. Matlab is able to read the images, but the further the frame is along the video, the more time it takes.

```
tic;I=read(v,1);toc
Elapsed time is 0.264011 seconds.
tic;I=read(v,2000);toc
Elapsed time is 32.859614 seconds.
```

Also, I'm not sure if this is related, but Matlab cannot determine the number of frames in the file:

```
 v=VideoReader('S1140007 (~200 cubes, large).MP4');

Warning: Unable to determine the number of frames in this file.
```

I've tried using two versions R2012b and R2015a, and the problem persists.
On a different machine, however, the number of frames can be determined and the reading times don't get longer, so obviously there's something configured wrong on my machine.
I there a known solution for this problem (can this be related to codecs somehow?), or maybe an alternative method of reading one image at a time (readFrame is not relevant for my needs).

Any help would be appreciated,
Aviram

Comment: yes, since it is unable to determine the number of frames, it is processing it in order until it reaches the 2000th. I think the best solution here is to convert your mp4 file into a .seq file where the frames are indexed for fast execution. Upon converting to Seq (which should take some time), Matlab should have indexed the frames. Details here: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/examples/convert-between-image-sequences-and-video.html?refresh=true

Comment: I thought so...
I really don't want to do any conversions. I need the RGB contents of the images to stay the same as in the original, and conversions often change it...

Comment: The alternative is to read in all frames and save it into a matrix and then index the matrix, again, this does not save you any time if you are only looking for the 2000th frame, but should save you time if you are indexing multiple frames since it only need to traverse the video file once.

Comment: Thanks, but I do look for a single image each time (these are very large). I really need to understand why matlab can't determine the number of frames, apparently.

Comment: is the frame rate variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so this is not exactly an answer, but a workaround...
It seems that to set the NumberofFrames property in the videoreader object created for a video with an undetermined number of frames, one needs to read the last frame using the following code (as mentioned in the documentation of VideoReader):

```
v=VideoReader('path.mp4');
l=read(v,inf);
```

This sets the number of frames in the video, and allows for indexing and quick reading of single frames from the video. However, this only works in matlab r2012b. In 2015a, the NumberofFrames property is set by the read(v,inf) trick, but the reading is still very time-consuming, for some reason.
I'm not sure why this happens, and as I've said, some of the other machines I've checked were able to read my files properly (but some didn't), so this is far from completed. It is not clear why it cannot determine the number of frames, or why there's any variability between computers and why in some versions the last(v, inf) works and in others only partially.